# Trigger Python when a new row is added to Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have connected Python to Google Sheet through API under Google Cloud Platform . My project requires me to retrieve the new data whenever it is added to Google Sheet. Is there a way to trigger Python code to run to get the last row of the Google Sheet?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how your python script is run.

For example, if it's a cloud function, you can run it pretty easily with something like

```
function executePythonFunction() {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('<YOUR-PYTHON-CLOUD-FUNCTION-URL>');

}
```

by creating [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for **Change** event

Comment: Hi @roma, thanks for the input. Sorry I didn't give enough information. My Python is run on my local PC, its not in cloud. I connected it with Google Spreadsheet, but not sure how to create such a trigger.

Comment: You cannot actually run local script from GAS(only with polling). To trigger something from GAS it has to be somewhere in the internet. Easiest way is to deploy cloud function.

Comment: That's right. My Project is to save Zoom recordings to Google Drive. I'm using a Webhook to send me the download URL and some other info about the recordings. I use GAS to catch the webhook and display them on the Google Sheets. What my python code does is it will download the Video from a Download URL and store it in Local PC, then it will upload the video to Google Drive (which I'm not sure how to do yet). Since the video could be more than 1GB, it seems like that is the only way. If you have any other way, please give me some suggestion. Thanks a lot for your input.